# No dual boot option for windows after installing new version of ubuntu

Tags: grub2, system-installation, xubuntu

Installed ubuntu along with windows 7. But since then it is automatically starting ubuntu 14.04 and not showing any option to boot windows.
While installation I let it use default options to erase previous version and install this one.
Being new to ubuntu expecting a bit detailed answer.Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: Looks like you have deleted the windows partition

Comment: @Mohammedaadhil not so fast... Please run `sudo update-grub` from a terminal in Ubuntu and try again.

Comment: No the partitions for windows exist. Actually I dint use custom installation. Just let ubuntu remove previous version and install new one.

Comment: "While installation I let it use default options to erase previous version and install this one"....What do you mean by this????Did you try to upgrade using liveusb ???

Comment: Yes. I used a live usb.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the `shift` key after the BIOS screen. That forces the grub menu to show up, but +1 for Mohammed aadhil's comment. It really looks like it.

Comment: The windows partition is there.

Comment: Glad to hear, pls mark Mohammed aadhil's answer as accepted answer, because it worked

Answer (score 0):

Type this in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Select `recommended boot-repair`